# Concatenate String and Is Operator

Tags: c#, operators, order-of-execution

I do not understand why this code does throw a nullref.
I think it has something to do with the priority of the 'plus' operator and the 'is' operator but I am really not sure why.

```
 return "somestring " + B is not null  ? $" {B.Property}" : "empty";
```

Full sample:

```
internal class Program
 {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         var a = new A();
         Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
         Console.ReadKey();
     }
 }

 public class A
 {
     public B? B  { get; set; }

     public override string ToString()
     {
         return "somestring " + B is not null  ? $" {B.Property}" : "empty"; //nullref 
         return "somestring " + (B is not null ? $" {B.Property}" : "empty"); //works
     }
 }

 public class B
 {
     public string Property { get; set; } = "Property";
 }
```

Comment: you can't string concat a string and a null value. the `+` has a higher precedence than `is`

Comment: `"somestring " + (B is not null ? $" {B.Property}" : "empty")` - please, note '(...)'

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the problem is in the *execution order*:

```
"somestring " + B is not null  ? $" {B.Property}" : "empty
```

1. `"somestring " + B` (will be `"something " + null == "something "`)
2. `"somestring " is not null` (`true`, since `"something "` is not null)
3. `$" {B.Property}"` - *exception is thrown* since `B` is `null`

Let's add parenthesis to show the actual order:

```
(("somestring " + B) is not null) ? $" {B.Property}" : "empty
```

In the second version

```
"somestring " + (B is not null ? $" {B.Property}" : "empty")
```

we have a different order

1. `(B is not null ? $" {B.Property}" : "empty")` - `"empty"`, since `B` is `null`.
2. `"somestring " + "empty" == "something empty"`

Comment: Ah, thank you I got it. ("somestring " + B) is not null) was a great sample to understand it.